# Enable disable button from controller in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button which needs to be controlled on the basis of if the user has entered the values in the html page.

I have binded model to the text field and set a disabled variable on the $scope, which is enabled/disabled on the value of the input field model.

Here is the HTML

```
<!--This button should be disabled if no value is enterd in both the field-->
  <input type='button' value='click' ng-disabled='disabled'>
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="first">
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model='last'>
```

And here is the correponding angular controller.

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.disabled = !$scope.first || !$scope.last;

})
```

It runs for the first time, but then don't show changes on the basis of later modifications.

As per my understanding angular uses two way binding, so if I am modifying anything on the view it should be reflected on the controller, and then anything changed on the controller should be reflected on the view.
What wrong I am doing here?

PS: I dont want to use form
I want to avoid the onChange event on the text input field.

Please refer the plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/L5wkcpNzMMBZxtcitJwk?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-disabled='!first || !last'`.

The following logic seems to work, at least in your Plunker:

```
<input type='button' value='click' ng-disabled='!first || !last'>
<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="first">
<br>
<input type="text" ng-model='last'>
```

It is true that the scoped variable `$scope.first` and `$scope.last` are two-way bound to the controller.  This means that any change in the input boxes should automatically reflect in the state of these variables.  But `disabled` is a computed quantity, and this is calculated once, at the time the controller loads, but not again in your code.  Hence, `disabled` appears to always be `true`, even after you have entered text into both input boxes.

## Plunker

Comment: Thanks for giving the proper explanation. I was sure that ng-change will work as suggested in other answer, but it will be last resort I will look for.

Comment: @Pankaj If you needed to do _other_ things upon a change event, then you can consider going with Sajeetharan's answer.  But for your simple case, I would prefer to not have to add extra logic to your controller.

Comment: Going by this approach lets say I have n number of fields, rather than first and last, so it will add up a lengthy expression for ng-disabled, is there a nice clean way to achieve this?
Again ng-change is last resort

Comment: I don't see a clean way of doing this, which would not involve checking each field to see whether or not it be "truthy" (i.e. has something in it).

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will go with ng-change that, dont want to put much of logic on the view

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by detecting the changes in the inputs

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.disabled = !$scope.first || !$scope.last;
  }    
})
```

HTML

```
 <input type='button' value='click' ng-disabled='disabled'>
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-change="change()" ng-model="first">
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-change="change()" ng-model='last'>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VkbcjdWVqsjYewgygySR?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {

     $scope.disabled = !$scope.first=="" || !$scope.last == "";

})
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one. i hope it helps:

```
      $scope.disabled=($scope.first==""?true:($scope.last==""?true:false))
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What did you do and why does it work?

Comment: actuly i placed the ternary operator.First of all if will check that first is empty or not if not then it will check to last

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<input type='button' value='click' ng-disabled='first.length==0||last.length==0||first==undefined||last==undefined'>
     <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="first">
     <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model='last'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the plunker. Please chack it and let me know.

js code:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('myController', function($scope){

  $scope.disabled = true;

  $scope.func=function() {
   $scope.disabled = true;
    if($scope.first && $scope.last) {
      $scope.disabled=false;
    }
  }

})
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='myController'>

  <!--This button should be disabled if no value is enterd in both the field-->
  <input type='button' value='click' ng-disabled='disabled'>
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="first" ng-change="func()">
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model='last' ng-change="func()">
</body>

</html>
```